# OpenGL driver crash on glTexture2D

Tags: opengl, crash, driver, lwjgl

with the following Kotlin/JVM/LWJGL + java.nio.ByteBuffer + OpenGL code it seems I can crash some driver of mine:

```
val texture = glGenTextures()
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture)

val w = 1026
val h = 1029

val byteBuffer = ByteBuffer
    .allocateDirect(w*h)
    .position(0)

glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_R8, w, h, 0, GL_RED, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, byteBuffer)
```

Executing this after the usual GLFW+OpenGL init, this results in a crash of the application and the following message:

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x00007ff98593509c, pid=13572, tid=15424
#
# JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment (12.0.1+12) (build 12.0.1+12)
# Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (12.0.1+12, mixed mode, sharing, tiered, compressed oops, g1 gc, windows-amd64)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [atio6axx.dll+0x1bb509c]
#
# No core dump will be written. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# C:\Users\Antonio\Documents\IdeaProjects\VideoStudio\hs_err_pid13572.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#
```

Is there something I can do about this, but to avoid non-power-of-2-textures?

I tested some resolutions, and only got crashes with textures with width or height > 1024.
In the case of 1026 x 1029 (and some more, e.g. 1590 x 2244) I get a crash in 100% of the cases.

I am using an RX 580, R5 2600, Win 10, Radeon Drivers updated to Recommended, just in case it would change something.

Comment: Have you set `GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT` to `1` somewhere?  Or is it still the default of `4`?

Comment: Thx a lot! :D
I works that way :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default alignment for rows in the image data is 4 bytes. Unless your texture has a width which is a multiple of 4, you have to supply additional bytes for padding at the end of each row.

The other option is to change the unpack alignment to 1 byte by calling

```
glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);
```

before calling `glTexImage2D`.